My '50s Coleman furnace either won’t light or takes a long time to light
Last winter it worked great but this year it sometimes doesn’t want to ignite. I put a new thermostat face on and it lit right up but the next day it wouldn’t light. I’ve cleaned out spider webs and blew it off. It is working now but why would it work intermittently? It’s under the floor and is a pain to get to. Any thoughts?

~75 years without knowing if any maintenance done on it, it could be a lot.  Dirty filters, dirty/clog nozzles, don't know if any safety sensors/features on it, clogged chimney.

Hope I work as good as your furnace when I hit 75.  At 65 sometimes I take a long time to light also.
